# Can you use MongoDB map/reduce to migrate data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapreduce, mongoid

I have a large collection where I want to modify all the documents by populating a field.

A simple example might be caching the comment count on each post:

```
class Post
  field :comment_count, type: Integer
  has_many :comments
end
class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I can run it in serial with something like:

```
Post.all.each do |p|
  p.udpate_attribute :comment_count, p.comments.count
end
```

But it's taking 24 hours to run (large collection). I was wondering if mongo's map/reduce could be used for this?  But I haven't seen a great example yet.

I imagine you would map off the comments collection and then store the reduced results in the posts collection.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB map/reduce to "help" migrate data,
unfortunately you can't use it to do a completely server-side migration.
You are on the right track, the basic idea would be to:

1. map each comment to emit(post_id, {comment_count: 1}) ---> {_id: post_id, value: {comment_count: 1}}
2. reduce to value {comment_count: N} N is the count-sum ---> {_id: post_id, value: {comment_count: N}}
3. specify output option {reduce: 'posts'} to reduce the results of map/reduce comment_counts back into the posts collection

After somewhat extensive investigation, I found that you can come close,
but there is a problem that blocks you from a completely server-side migration.
The result of reduce has the shape {_id: KEY, value: MAP_REDUCE_VALUE}.
We're stuck with this shape for now, there doesn't seem to be a way around it.
So you can neither get at the full original document outside of this shape as input to reduce (in fact, you will loose data outside this shape),
nor update the document outside of this shape as a result of reduce.
Therefore, the "final" update to your posts collection will have to be done programmatically via the client.
It looks like fixing this would be a good modification request.

Below find a working example that demonstrates using MongoDB map/reduce in Ruby for calculating all comment_counts.
I then programmatically use the map_reduce_results collection to update comment_count in the posts collection.
The reduce function is stripped down from the attempt to use out: {reduce: 'posts'}

You can verify my answer with a little experimentation,
or I can post the non-working completely server-side attempt on request if you want,
complete with fixed models.
Hope that this helps to understand MongoDB map/reduce in Ruby.

test/unit/comment_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class CommentTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @map_reduce_results_name = 'map_reduce_results'
    delete_all
  end

  def delete_all
    Post.delete_all
    Comment.delete_all
    Mongoid.database.drop_collection(@map_reduce_results_name)
  end

  def dump(title = nil)
    yield
    puts title
    Post.all.to_a.each do |post|
      puts "#{post.to_json} #{post.comments.collect(&:text).to_json}"
    end
  end

  def generate
    (2+rand(2)).times do |p|
      post = Post.create(text: 'post_' + p.to_s)
      comments = (2+rand(3)).times.collect do |c|
        Comment.create(text: "post_#{p} comment_#{c}")
      end
      post.comments = comments
    end
  end

  def generate_and_migrate(title = nil)
    dump(title + ' generate:') { generate }
    dump(title + ' migrate:') { yield }
  end

  test "map reduce migration" do
    generate_and_migrate('programmatic') do
      Post.all.each do |p|
        p.update_attribute :comment_count, p.comments.count
      end
    end
    delete_all
    generate_and_migrate('map/reduce') do
      map = "function() { emit( this.post_id, {comment_count: 1} ); }"
      reduce = <<-EOF
        function(key, values) {
          var result = {comment_count: 0};
          values.forEach(function(value) { result.comment_count += value.comment_count; });
          return result;
        }
      EOF
      out = @map_reduce_results_name #{reduce: 'posts'}
      result_coll = Comment.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, out: out)
      puts "#{@map_reduce_results_name}:"
      result_coll.find.each do |doc|
        p doc
        Post.find(doc['_id']).update_attribute :comment_count, doc['value']['comment_count'].to_i
      end
    end
  end
end
```

test output (sorry about the mix of JSON and Ruby inspect)

```
Run options: --name=test_map_reduce_migration

# Running tests:

programmatic generate:
{"_id":"4fcae3bde4d30b21e2000001","comment_count":null,"text":"post_0"} ["post_0 comment_0","post_0 comment_1","post_0 comment_2"]
{"_id":"4fcae3bde4d30b21e2000005","comment_count":null,"text":"post_1"} ["post_1 comment_1","post_1 comment_0","post_1 comment_2","post_1 comment_3"]
{"_id":"4fcae3bde4d30b21e200000a","comment_count":null,"text":"post_2"} ["post_2 comment_1","post_2 comment_3","post_2 comment_0","post_2 comment_2"]
programmatic migrate:
{"_id":"4fcae3bde4d30b21e2000001","comment_count":3,"text":"post_0"} ["post_0 comment_0","post_0 comment_1","post_0 comment_2"]
{"_id":"4fcae3bde4d30b21e2000005","comment_count":4,"text":"post_1"} ["post_1 comment_1","post_1 comment_0","post_1 comment_2","post_1 comment_3"]
{"_id":"4fcae3bde4d30b21e200000a","comment_count":4,"text":"post_2"} ["post_2 comment_1","post_2 comment_3","post_2 comment_0","post_2 comment_2"]
map/reduce generate:
{"_id":"4fcae3bee4d30b21e200000f","comment_count":null,"text":"post_0"} ["post_0 comment_0","post_0 comment_1"]
{"_id":"4fcae3bee4d30b21e2000012","comment_count":null,"text":"post_1"} ["post_1 comment_2","post_1 comment_0","post_1 comment_1"]
{"_id":"4fcae3bee4d30b21e2000016","comment_count":null,"text":"post_2"} ["post_2 comment_0","post_2 comment_1","post_2 comment_2","post_2 comment_3"]
map_reduce_results:
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4fcae3bee4d30b21e200000f'), "value"=>{"comment_count"=>2.0}}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4fcae3bee4d30b21e2000012'), "value"=>{"comment_count"=>3.0}}
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4fcae3bee4d30b21e2000016'), "value"=>{"comment_count"=>4.0}}
map/reduce migrate:
{"_id":"4fcae3bee4d30b21e200000f","comment_count":2,"text":"post_0"} ["post_0 comment_0","post_0 comment_1"]
{"_id":"4fcae3bee4d30b21e2000012","comment_count":3,"text":"post_1"} ["post_1 comment_2","post_1 comment_0","post_1 comment_1"]
{"_id":"4fcae3bee4d30b21e2000016","comment_count":4,"text":"post_2"} ["post_2 comment_0","post_2 comment_1","post_2 comment_2","post_2 comment_3"]
.

Finished tests in 0.072870s, 13.7231 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```